# Replace text in a file using sed on windows

Tags: windows, command-line, sed

I am trying to replace a string in a .ism file using the SED command but it is failing for me.
The line in the file is the product version which I want to change in every build.

```
<row><td>ProductVersion</td><td>1.0.0</td><td/></row>
```

And here is the command I'm trying:

`c:\rt_cygwin\bin\sed -i -r "s/ProductVersion\\"+[0-9].+[0-9].+[0-9]
/ProductVersion\"1.0.%BUILD_NUMBER%/" "D:\lm.ism"`

Thanks

Comment: Your pattern can found a `ProductVersion\1.0.0`, but the </td><td> part is missing, you could try `ProductVersion.*[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]`

Answer (score 1):

c:\rt_cygwin\bin\sed -i -r "s/ProductVersion</td>[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]/ProductVersion 1.0.%BUILD_NUMBER%/" "D:\lm.ism"

You have extra quotes that is not in the example line that should be removed and as @jeb pointed out the  portion is missing.